# Finishing main activity cause android application to restart

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I'm facing strange issue in an android application. Whenever I finish activity or even force close application it got restarted.

Here is what application flow:

Application opens with Splash screen which is an activity and then go to Main Activity where content shown in a fragment. Now when I finish main activity on back press then application got restarted instead of closing.

I'm starting `MainActivity` like this

```
Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(mainIntent);
```

and in `MainActivity` i'm finishing it like this

```
MainActivity.this.finish();
```

and exiting application like this

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
System.exit(0);
```

How to resolve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Post your code maybe.

Comment: you need to finish you spalsh screen when you start your main activity.
i think problem is you are not finishing your splash screen.

Comment: Why down voting instead of answering the problem. Those who did not understand the question please ask for clarification instead of down voting.

Comment: I think  Prashant is right. you probably missed something in Splash screen. so check if you close splash screen before you call Main Activity .

Comment: @MukeshJha you asked question but you didn't explained it well with your code. someone may have downvoted it for that.

Comment: @Prashant You are right. Finishing SplashActivity before starting MainActivity does the work. I was missing this. Thanks

Comment: @MukeshJha mark answer as accepted as it solved your problem

Comment: @Prashant Already done it buddy... :) You can see one up vote on your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should start MainActivity with flags as

```
Intent launchNextActivity;
launchNextActivity = new Intent(B.class, A.class);
launchNextActivity.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
launchNextActivity.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);                  
launchNextActivity.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
startActivity(launchNextActivity);
```

Now in the MainActivity where you want to implement onBackPressed to close the app, you may do something like this,

```
private Boolean exit = false;
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (exit) {
            finish(); // finish activity
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Press Back again to Exit.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            exit = true;
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    exit = false;
                }
            }, 3 * 1000);

        }

}
```

Now when you press back button it will give toast to "Press back gain to exit", and if user presses back button within 3 seconds the app will exit

Answer (score 1):

After you start `MainActivity` call `finish()` , that will solve your problem.

In `SplashActivity.java`

```
Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(mainIntent);
finish();
```

You don't need to do anything else in `MainActivity`

Comment: Why on earth would you override `onBackPressed()` and call `finish()`? Do you have any idea what the default implementation of `onBackPressed()` actually does? It calls `finish()`!

Comment: @DavidWasser my mistake

Answer (score 1):

Do not do this:

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
System.exit(0);
```

There is no need to kill the process. Android will do this when and if it wants to. This is the reason your app is getting restarted. Android thinks it crashed, and is restarting it for the user.

Comment: Thanks, you are absolutely right. Android restarts application when we kill the process as it assumes application crashed.

Comment: No but every app I ever downloaded does this. Pressing back twice calls onDestroy and ends the app; but it is immediately restarted. You have to actually swipe away the app to completely stop it from running. However I think that calling finish() will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

can you post some code?? i post this code may be this will help you.

inside your Mainactivity.

```
 @Override
   public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    finish();
  }

@Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            finish();
            break;

    }
    return (super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
}
```

Comment: Why on earth would you override `onBackPressed()` and call `finish()`? Do you have any idea what the default implementation of `onBackPressed()` actually does? It calls `finish()`!

Answer (score 0):

Buddy your code is

```
Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(mainIntent);
MainActivity.this.finish();
```

Here what's wrong with your code is that you are first opening MainActivity and once it's opened you are closing it in very next line.

```
Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(mainIntent);
finish(); // or write this as SplashActivity.this.finish();
```

This piece of code will finish your current activity that is SplashActivity and MainActivity will remain active. Good Luck.

Comment: he might not written this line in `SplashActivity` : `MainActivity.this.finish();` 
if he really did that IDE must have given him compile time error.

Comment: No! there is nothing wrong with this. This code  MainActivity.this.finish(); will run fine. It's just an another way of closing the activity, his placement of code is wrong though.

Answer (score 0):

@MukeshJha problem is that you are not finishing your first activity i.e. `SplashActivity` so it was remain in stack in stop state when you started `MainActivity` and then you are finishing your `MainActivity` so that leads to restart previous `SplashActivity` from stop state.

To avoid again restart `SplashActivity` you need to finish it whenever you are starting new activity.

solution is to start MainActivity like this way,

```
Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(mainIntent);
finish(); // this will cause to finish SplashActivity.
```